# Finding all intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ for which the function is monotonically increasing/decreasing

Tags: functions

Given $f(x) = x^{3}-3x+5$. How do I find all intervals for which the function is monotonically increasing and decreasing?

I have $f'(x)=3x^{2}-3=0 \Rightarrow  x=\pm 1$. And $f''(x)=6x$, so $f''(-1)=-6<0$ and $f''(1)=6>0$, so the function has a minimum and a maximum.

So it is definitely increasing and decreasing on some intervals.

What should I specifically look for here to find the intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO need to calculate $f''$.

$f'(x)=3x^2-3$. When $|x|>1$ then $f'(x)>0$. So $f$ is **strictly** increasing in $(1,\infty)\cup (-\infty ,-1)$. Again , $f'(x)<0$ for $|x|<1$. That is , $f$  is **strictly** monotone decreasing in $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)$ is increasing whenever the derivative $f'(x)$ is positive, and the function is decreasing whenever the derivative is negative.

You have the correct derivative (though there's a typo - it should be $f'(x)=3x^2-3$, but I assume it's a typo because you have the correct solutions for $f'(x)=0$). Now you just need to figure out where that function is positive and where it is negative.